# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: typescript, http

I want to download a zip file from server side in Google Chrome, the server was written by rust. The server side return the rust actix NameFile like this:

```
pub async fn download_project(
    _req: HttpRequest,
    form: web::Json<DownloadProj>
) -> actix_web::Result<impl actix_web::Responder> {
    let zip_path = handle_compress_proj(&form.0);
    match NamedFile::open(&zip_path) {
        Ok(fe) => {
            // Ok(NamedFile::into_response(fe, &req))
            Ok( fe.use_last_modified(true) )
        },
        Err(_) => Err(actix_web::error::ErrorBadRequest("File not Found") )
    }
}
```

this is the return content look like:

```
PK�=!X�f�@F)45e7bfd8344442049c22dd2e37f24ef6/main.texE�1� н��݃x�.�6���&���N����|�y�Z{*-l�mO�>y�i@�����PK.�=!X�f�@F)�45e7bfd8344442049c22dd2e37f24ef6/main.texPKW�
```

now I want to parse the content to `.zip` file in the client side typescript like this:

```
const handleProjDownload = (docItem: TexProjectModel) => {
        let proj : QueryDownload = {
            project_id: docItem.project_id,
            version: "1"
        };
        downloadProj(proj).then((resp) => {
            debugger
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(resp);
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.download = 'file.zip';
            link.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        });
    }
```

this client side typescript code shows error:

```
ProjectTab.tsx:74 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
    at ProjectTab.tsx:74:36
```

Am I missing something? is it possible to parse the file on the client side? I have already tried to convert to blob on the client side like this:

```
downloadProj(proj).then((resp) => {
            debugger
            const bl = resp.blob();
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(bl);
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.download = 'file.zip';
            link.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
       });
```

told the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: resp.blob is not a function`. I alos tried the code like this:

```
downloadProj(proj).then((resp) => {
    const blob = new Blob([resp], { type: 'application/zip' }); 
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
});
```

But I can not open the downloaded zip file. when I using this command to download the file from server side, it works fine:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"project_id": "5ef2057551c24b5aa4d0e2cdadcbc524","version": "1"}'  -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbxxxxx" -o filename1.zip https://tex.example.top/tex/project/download
```

BTW, this is the `downloadProj` function look like:

```
export function downloadProj(req: QueryDownload) {
  const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'put',
    url: '/tex/project/download',
    data: JSON.stringify(req)
  };
  const actionTypeString: string = ProjectActionType[ProjectActionType.DOWNLOAD_PROJ];
  return XHRClient.requestWithActionType(config, actionTypeString, store);
}
```

Comment: Did you try converting response to blob? Something like this `resp.blob().then((blob) => { creating object URL and other }`. Maybe setting up `responseType: 'blob'` is needed on server side.

Comment: yes, I have tried to convert to blob but told that blob is not a function.

Comment: `const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/zip' }); const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); window.open(url);`

Comment: Does it work for you? If so, I can write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the point is to convert response to blob and then make object URL. You can do it like this:

```
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/zip' }); 
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
window.open(url); // this will open download window
```

For this to work, it's needed to specify `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` to request.

Comment: the file could successfully generated but I could not open it.

Comment: What error are you getting? I'm not sure I got it right, you can open it when you download it using `curl` but can't when using client?

Comment: yes, I can open and unzip the file downloaded by curl but could not unzip or open it using code with typescript.

Comment: this is the error when open the downloaded file: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467916/inappropriate-file-type-or-format-when-open-a-zip-file

Comment: Try exactly as I wrote. Delete `link` variable and don't revoke URL. Use `window.open(url)`. Code I provided is from my project so I'm sure it's valid.

Comment: I have tried what you said but still could not work as expect.

Comment: What does `downloadProj()` return? Function I used returns `Observable` like this `return this.http.get(path, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})`. Try adding `responseType` to request.

Comment: it looks like I am missing `arraybuffer` response type.

Comment: yes, it works now, I add the arraybuffer response type and it works now.

Comment: Great. Glad to be of some help. And Happy New year :)